# stored procedure parameter of CSV input to return all records

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I have the following Oracle stored procedure that takes on a string of CSV of user ID's which would return the list of users to the output cursor which works fine:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE GET_USERS_BY_IDS
(
  v_cur OUT sys_refcursor
  ,v_userIdsCsv IN varchar2 DEFAULT ''
) AS 
BEGIN
open v_cur for
with userIds
 as
 (
 select
   trim( substr (txt,
         instr (txt, ',', 1, level  ) + 1,
         instr (txt, ',', 1, level+1) - instr (txt, ',', 1, level) -1 ) )
     as token
    from (select ','||v_userIdsCsv||',' txt
            from dual)
  connect by level <=
     length(v_userIdsCsv)-length(replace(v_userIdsCsv,',',''))+1
  )
  select
    id
    ,lastname
    ,firstname
    from
      users
    where
      id in (select * from userIds);
END GET_USERS_BY_IDS;
```

so by doing `exec GET_USERS_BY_IDS(:cur1, '123,456')` I can get users of IDs of 123 and 456. However I would like to return ALL users if I pass in an empty string, i.e. `exec GET_USERS_BY_IDS(:cur1, '')` would return all users. What do I have to change in the sproc code to accomplish that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a more efficient way to do this now. In the `where` statement, I can just short-circuit it if the input parameter is a blank:

```
where
  v_userIdsCsv = '' or
  id in (select * from userIds);
```

Comment: I don't believe you can have a where clause test where empty string = empty string. Make your default value for v_userIdsCsv '1' then make your where clause test for v_userIdsCsv = '1' and it should work.

Comment: You accepted an answer that does not work.  If v_userIdsCsv is an empty string you will not get all users as you expect.  Proof: `select sysdate from dual where '' = '';`.  This works though as per my comment above: `select sysdate from dual where '1' = '1';`.  Please edit this post to show a valid working answer so as not to confuse future searchers.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this solution using REGEXP functions which I feel simplifies things.  I also incorporated the test from my comment as well.  Note the REGEXP handles a NULL list element too:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE GET_USERS_BY_IDS
(
  v_cur OUT sys_refcursor
  ,v_userIdsCsv IN varchar2 DEFAULT '1'
) AS 
BEGIN
open v_cur for
with userIds
 as
 (
  select trim( regexp_substr(v_userIdsCsv, '(.*?)(,|$)', 1, level, NULL, 1) ) as token
  from dual
  connect by level <= regexp_count(v_userIdsCsv, ',') + 1  
  )
  select
    id
    ,lastname
    ,firstname
    from
      users
    where v_userIdsCsv = '1' -- Empty list returns all users
    OR id in (select * from userIds);
END GET_USERS_BY_IDS;
```

Its untested so let us know what happens if you test it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean, something as simple as

```
BEGIN
  if v_userIdsCsv = '' then 
    open v_cur for select id, lastname, firstname from users
  else (rest of your code)
  end if;
```

?

OK, with the confirmation in comments...

It seems you should be able to change the WHERE condition at the very end:

```
where 
   v_userIdsCsv = '' or id in (select * from userIds);
```

Answer (score 0):

Outer join between user and user_ids. And clever where condition. 
Has it helped?

```
  with csv as (select '321,333' aa from dual) 

       ,userIds
     as
 (
 select
   trim( substr (txt,
         instr (txt, ',', 1, level  ) + 1,
         instr (txt, ',', 1, level+1) - instr (txt, ',', 1, level) -1 ) ) 
     as token
    from (select ','||(select aa from csv )||',' txt
            from dual)
  connect by level <=
     length((select aa from csv ))-length(replace((select aa from csv),',',''))+1
  )
  select
     user_id
    ,username
    from
      all_users a
   left join userIds b on a.user_id  = b.token
   where nvl2((select aa from csv),b.token,a.user_id) = a.user_id
```